# Data repair with hinted handoff disabled

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've got 2 datacentres, dc1 has 2 nodes and dc2 has 1 node. Replication strategy: Network topology, dc1: 2, dc2: 1. I've disabled hinted handoff in the yaml of all 3 nodes. Now I disable one node in dc1, and write 100k entries via C++. After that, I start the node I had killed earlier. After this, I stop the 2 nodes which were running when I had written the data. Now only one node is up.

When I run the program, having the read statement for all those 100k entries, I was expecting, that since this node was down at the time of writing, and hinted handoff was also disabled, therefore, no rows should be fetched. However, I was surprised to see that around 2000 rows were still fetched.
What exactly happened. How did the data reach the node?

Cassandra: 3.0.14

Comment: Did you restart after changing `hinted_handoff_enabled = false`? Have a look at `debug.log` to ensure no hinted handoffs happen.

Comment: I had restated the node but I didn't check the debug logs at that time. Does read repair also occur in the background without making any read request?

Comment: Did you also used this value https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters ?

Comment: @Horia missed this one :)

Comment: exactly which value are you talking about? Like I said, I had disable hinted handoff.

Comment: hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters